# How to execute binaries on QNX SPD 7.0 target

Tags: executable, qnx

I'm able to execute a "Hello World" code on Momentics IDE on a Windows Development host by networking it with the QNX target using QConn(IP) on VMWare hypervisor.

I want to execute the binaries on QNX directly. How can that be done?

[image: QNX Momentics IDE]

Answer (score 1):

You should connect your QNX target to momentics, transfer your binary and execute it.
1) On top of the serial connection is needed a network connection
2) Create a Target project on the IDE (from IDE: File/New/Others… /QNX/QNX Target System Project...)
3) To run and debug the newly built program on the target system, it is sufficient select the program Binaries in the Project Explorer and, from the dropdown menu beside the “bug” icon on the toolbar, select Debug As/C/C++ QNX Application.

The file is transfered in the tmp directory and executed in debug (like with wmWare).

Through Momentics it is also possible to transfer the binary in the FS of the QNX target (if Flash FS it is permanent).

In alternative I'm able to write files in the QNX FS using SCP (winSCP windows program, SCP command in Linux)
[Momentics debug perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPb1g.png)